# Autosys : Terminating BOX does not terminate individual jobs within?

Tags: autosys

**Scenario :** Have an Autosys Box Job `BOX_JOB` with 3 individual job - `JOB1,2,3`.

**Problem** : Terminating the `BOX_JOB` , does'nt terminate the individual jobs - `JOB1,2,3` running.

Wondering on `CA Workload Automation` if it's possible to terminate the `BOX_JOB` , that `will automatically terminate any individual jobs` that might be in running state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JILs for JOB1,2,3 need to have the **job_terminator** attribute set to **true** so they will each terminate if the box terminates.