# When I kill parent job few of the child jobs are still running . how to fix it?

Tags: autosys

When I kill parent job few of the child jobs are still running . how to fix it to kill all child jobs when we kill parent job

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autosys : Terminating BOX does not terminate individual jobs within?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026394/autosys-terminating-box-does-not-terminate-individual-jobs-within)

Answer (score 0):

Set the **job_terminator** attribute in the jil of each of the child jobs to **TRUE** so they will terminate when their containing box terminates.

Comment: job_terminator was true for child jobs ,all jobs are working fine except 3 jobs.